# Magento 2 Custom Admin Action Redirected to Dashboard

Tags: admin, magento2, redirect, url-key, admin-controller

I am taking the Magento 2 fundamentals development course and the Admin Router / Controller exercise seems out of date. The router does work, but the controller does not, it always just re-routes to the admin homepage. Code for router **app/code/Training/Test/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="test" frontName="test">
        <module name="Training_Test" before="Magento_Backend" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

Code for Admin controller **app/code/Training/Test/Controller/Adminhtml/Action/Index.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Training\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

public function execute()
    {
    die("test reached controller");
    }
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return true;
    }
}
```

When I go to the admin url of admin/test/action/index it just redirects and nothing happens. If I add a constructor and use xdebug, it shows that it reaches the controller constructor, but it never does the execute part. What am I missing?

Comment: I hope in your code function _isAllowed return true. In example "return" instruction is absence

Comment: @KAndy yes it is, thanks though. Edited my question to show that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This happens because 'secret key' is missing when you just type in URL manually.
Secret key feature is enabled by default and can be disabled here: `Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Admin => Security => Add Secret Key to URLs`. Then you should be able to reach your action.

Comment: @Alex Paliarush , how to make this work when security keys are enabled.?

Comment: @Aswanth Just add your action to the menu, and click on it. In this case Magento will add proper security key to the request

Comment: @AlexPaliarush Thanks It works for me.. and saved my time

Comment: This was the problem but why don't the course say about this condition in the exercise? I lost some hours checking this...  Grrrrrrr

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :) made my day

Comment: This is a temporary workaround that disables an intentional security feature - do not use this answer as a permanent solution on a public website! The answer fails to highlight that this is almost always a problem in your custom module routing logic - look there before resorting to this

Comment: as @ScottAnderson wrote this is a temporary solution and it generates a security issue! Check the answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192780/2004

Answer (score 18):

In `routes.xml` configuration file (`companyName/customModule/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`).
For me the solution was to have the route id and frontName have the same value. In your case this would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="asw_advanved" frontName="asw_advanved">
            <module name="Asw_Sample" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Changed  `<route id="Bmanager" frontName="bmanager">` to `<route id="bmanager" frontName="bmanager">` and now I can make a basic controller work as described the question body. Still no luck with my custom controllers. Edit: Actually one of my custom controllers started giving some errors. Much better than redirect with no erorrs.

Comment: You legend this saved me much time!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. What it happen?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's better to use that property:

```
/**
 * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_publicActions = ['action_name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

When attempting to access modules/functionality in the backend (Adminhtml), Magento checks for the presence of the secret `Form Keys`, and if/when someone does attempt to access an action and doesn't supply a FormKey (e.g: hotlinking the url) and/or supplies an Invalid FormKey - the Adminhtml AbstractAction (Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction) will route the user Admin UIX's defined Startup page (which is usually the Dashboard page)

[This mechanism serves a "security checkpoint" to prevent users from accessing portions of the Backend that they don't have access to]

---

When accessing options from the Admin UIX Menu - Magento will automatically add the FormKey for you.

---

To prevent the check for FormKey you have two options:

*(a) Turn off FormKey Validation*

**Navigation:** Stores -> Settings : Configuration -> Advanced : Admin -> Security -> Setup "Add Secret Key to URLs" to "No"

It's very important to remember that doing so will turn off Secret Key Validation, and therefore *may* make your application vulnerable.

[image: How To Turn Off FormKey Validation]

*(b) Turn off FormKey Validation for your controller*

Specify the action(s) you wish to exempt, from the FormKey check, in the "$_publicActions" attribute of your Admin Controller.

**protected $_publicActions = ['ENTER_NAME_OF_ACTION'];**

Code Example:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_publicActions = ['index'];

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "My Hello World! Controller";
    }

}
```

Comment: protected $_publicActions = ['ENTER_NAME_OF_ACTION']; save my day, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of the routing redirection with the security key enabled is the action url set in the menu.xml under /etc/adminhtml/

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Mycompany_Mymodule::top_level" module="Mycompany_Mymodule" resource="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="9999" title="My Module" parent="Magento_Sales::sales"/>
        <add action="mycompany_mymodule/profile/index" id="Mycompany::mycompany_mymodule_profile" module="mycompany_Mymodule" parent="Mycompany_Mymodule::top_level" resource="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="9999" title="My Module"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

The important value is the action parameter in the menu item. Pay attention to set the name of the module declared into the routes.xml into the id parameter. In my case: "mycompany_mymodule"

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="mymodule" id="mycompany_mymodule">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Mycompany_Mymodule"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I would like update this to help others!

If you use the getUrl() in the phtml file remember that the path that you will use is the name of the action defined in the menu.xml and not the frontName defined in the /adminhtml/routes.xml!

For instance this link will generates a **Request validation failed for action** :

```
<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('mymodule/profile/edit', ['subscriptions_profile_id' => $profile->getId()])) ?>
```

this is the solution:

```
<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('mycompany_mymodule/profile/edit', ['subscriptions_profile_id' => $profile->getId()])) ?>
```

Pay attention to the name of the module as parameter in the getUrl() method!

Answer (score 1):

`<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormKey()) ?>" />` will help

but you could add a brickpoing to
vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php

```
if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was max_input_vars in the php.ini file

Reference is at:
https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension/redirect-issue-after-saving-blog-post