# Magento 2 custom Admin controller redirect to Dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-controller

I am trying to add a new **Admin Menu** in **Magento 2** for first time. I followed these tutorials:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-menu-magento-2.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html

https://webkul.com/blog/create-admin-menu-and-controller-in-magento2/
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/10/magento2-admin-menu-route/

But right know, when click in my custom menu, it's redirecting me to dashboard, every time. I clear cache several time, logout and login again, but nothing.

I see this post: [Magento 2 Custom Admin Action Redirected to Dashboard](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92236/magento-2-custom-admin-action-redirected-to-dashboard) and says that it occurs for the absence of **secret key**, but the url in the menu have the secret key, but still redirects to dashboard.

Here are my files:

acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin">
                <resource id="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp" title="Mobile App" sortOrder="20">
                    <resource id="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp_appreport" title="Reportes de Servicio" sortOrder="10"></resource>
                    <resource id="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp_apporder" title="Ordenes de Surtido" sortOrder="20"></resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="morwi_mobileapp" frontName="morwi_mobileapp">
            <module name="Morwi_MobileApp" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp" title="Mobile App" module="Morwi_MobileApp" sortOrder="70" resource="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp"/>
        <add id="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp_appreport" title="Reportes de Servicio" module="Morwi_MobileApp" sortOrder="2" action="morwi_mobileapp/appreport" resource="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp_appreport" parent="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp"/>
        <add id="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp_apporder" title="Ordenes de Surtido" module="Morwi_MobileApp" sortOrder="3" action="morwi_mobileapp/apporder" resource="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp_apporder" parent="Morwi_MobileApp::mobileapp"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Morwi\MobileApp\Controller\Adminhtml\Apporder;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
        exit;
    }
}
```

I don't see nothing wrong. What could be happening?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

I have also the Appreport controller, but I didn´t add this before, beacause the content is very the same of the other controller:

Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Morwi\Mobileapp\Controller\Adminhtml\Appreport;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
        exit;
    }
}
```

But both controllers redirect me to Dashboard.

**EDIT 2:**
I am starting think that is something wrong with my Module. I tried put my code in **routes.xml** file in other module (a Third party extension) and add the **Index.php** in that module, and it seems to work right. But, it is strange. If I run: `php bin/magento module:status` my Module `Morwi_Mobileapp` is listed as enabled, and is displayed en `Admin Store > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`. Also, it has a row in **setup_module** table. So, with this, it is safe to say that Magento is detecting my module, right?

But it is like Magento ingores my **routes.xml** file, or is not relating the frontName **morwi_mobileapp** with my module **Morwi_Mobileapp** for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 Custom Admin Action Redirected to Dashboard](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92236/magento-2-custom-admin-action-redirected-to-dashboard)

Comment: In the menu action `morwi_mobileapp/appreport`. You're missing this controller. Take a look my answer.

Comment: Your code lines should work. Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: add the formkey under the form  <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey();?>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

At the end, I deleted my module completely and I did it all over again, and it works. I still do not know that I would have had a bad with the original module.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your execute method has no return value.
It should be:

```
$page = $this->pageFactory->create();
return $page;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Originally I have that, but I changed for test if execute() method was reached, but not...

Comment: Try putting a trailing slash on your menu actions: `morwi_mobileapp/apporder/`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look your `menu.xml`, there are two action controllers:

- `morwi_mobileapp/appreport`
- `morwi_mobileapp/apporder`

1) `app/code/Morwi/MobileApp/Controller/Adminhtml/Appreport/Index.php` for `morwi_mobileapp/appreport`. You're missing this controller.

2) `app/code/Morwi/MobileApp/Controller/Adminhtml/Apporder/Index.php` for `morwi_mobileapp/apporder`

**EDIT:**

Your `menu.xml` and `routes.xml` should be under `etc/adminhtml` folder.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I have also the Appreport controller, but the content is Is quite similar to the other. Both controllers redirect me to dashboard.

Comment: Did you clear Magento Cache and delete `var/generation`? I checked on my local machine it worked fine. Can you post your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no controller file so it will take you to dashboard page

You need to create controller same for Appreport, You have only created Apporder that is working fine. create controller for **Appreport**.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I have also the Appreport controller, but the content is Is quite similar to the other. Both controllers redirect me to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because 'secret key' is missing when you just type in URL manually. Secret key feature is enabled by default and can be disabled here:

> Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Admin => Security => Add Secret
>   Key to URLs

. Then you should be able to reach your action.

Comment: this is a useful workaround, but production-ready code should be able to be ran using this feature.