# How to create controller without creating menu in Adminhtml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-controller

I have referred below Article to display button in my Configuration page.

https://magecomp.com/blog/add-a-button-in-magento-2-stores-configuration-with-custom-action/

In file

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\System\Config\Button.php

there is a function where we can define our Ajax URL

```
public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(‘your action Url’);
    }
```

So for this, I want to create controller in Adminhtml which i can access using action url.
but all the examples i found also creates menu in sidebar in addition to controller action.

For example this one:
https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/admin-controller-creation-with-magento-2/

Is there any way to access controller action without creating menu?

**Edit:**
After some modification to code, I can get into the controller using below URL:

> my_backend_url/route_id/controller_name/index

but it redirects back me to Dashboard page.

As mentioned in this article:

[Magento 2 Custom Admin Action Redirected to Dashboard](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92236/magento-2-custom-admin-action-redirected-to-dashboard)

It's Secret Form Key issue.

We can get Secret form key only if we add controller to menu which i don't want to do!

Disabling Secret Form key is not what i prefer!

Comment: menu file is used to display menu in admin backend

Comment: yes i know and i don't want to display in menu. so i have not created menu.xml file

Comment: you can create controller without menu file but you can call controller using url

Comment: yes but i am not able to call controller using url

Comment: like this www.abc.com/admin/yout_route_id/controller_name

Comment: yes i could do that. but now i am redirected to dashboard page! any idea?

Comment: i think problem in url please share your route id or your controller file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer which worked for me is from this article:

[Magento 2 Custom Admin Action Redirected to Dashboard](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92236/magento-2-custom-admin-action-redirected-to-dashboard)

We can use **protected $_publicActions = ['ENTER_NAME_OF_ACTION'];** to turn off form key validation for specific controller like below:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_publicActions = ['index'];

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "My Hello World! Controller";
    }

}
```

It's better to disable form key for only my controller instead of everywhere in admin panel.

Please share if anyone has any better solution.

Answer (score -5):

Your namespace should be uppercase, not lowercase, if you want to go step by step
[How do I create a controller in magento 2](https://www.sky8g.com/technology/1957/)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/promotion